# Is using Enum the most practical way to keep city names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, enums

I am developing a web project with .net. In this project the city names will be selected in a combo box. That's why I'm considering keeping the city names as enums. Is there any easier and more practical way to do this?

Comment: have you considered the usage of a database?

Comment: also there are things like: http://geodb-cities-api.wirefreethought.com/

Comment: Write a wrapper class that provides the city names as strings along with any other metadata you need. Enums suffer from some drawnbacks: They need to be translated to/from strings when working with a UI and they are difficult to add to at runtime. The wrapper class could talk to a config file or database or whatever you choose, but the consumer of the wrapper class (the UI code) won't know or care about this.

Comment: yes I am using database

Comment: If you're using a database, why not load them from the database?

Comment: I want it to be selected when the user registers. This is an option, but I just wanted to find the most practical method. @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: There's nothing more frustrating (may be exaggeration) than a web application that insists that my address doesn't exist. How are you planning to ensure that the members of the enumeration are always up to date?

Comment: And is it OK for a developer's time to be involved if that list needs to be changed? And to have to redeploy the application if that list needs to be changed?

Comment: I understand. So you say that it is more practical to use the city information from a different table in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think ahead whether City is used in any part of the logic inside your app. Using City as enum will cause problem later when you want to remove a city, and the integer number representing the enum maybe reused for other city?

For example you have a city enum consist of New York, San Francisco and Seattle. When you store them in database, you either store it as number of 0,1,2 or as the string name of the city.

Down the road you may want to remove the Seattle, then you will need to patch the data table or update the code so that when you read Seattle from database, you needto map the enum properly or make it null.